# Woocommerce and Wordpress Permalinks

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, permalinks

I am trying to get the permalinks to work correctly on my site. We have wordpress 4.1 and the latest version of woocommerce set up.

My problem is when I set the wordpress permalinks to %postname% it makes it so I can't navigate to many of the pages in my site. For example I can go to My Account but not to edit my account address.

With the permalinks set to %postname% I get these URLs

My Account: http://www.studiobenna.com/jf/my-account/ (works)

Edit Address: http://www.studiobenna.com/jf/my-account/edit-address/billing (doesn't work).

If I set my permalink structure to default everything works;

My Account:http://www.studiobenna.com/jf/?page_id=315

Edit Address: http://www.studiobenna.com/jf/?page_id=315&edit-address=billing

I have tried changing the WooCommerce permalink structure to various different settings but nothing works. Any ideas?

This also affects all of my archive pages as well as a bunch of other woocommerce pages.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've tried to remove /shop/ from the WooCommerce URL, which causes conflicts in WordPress. http://docs.woothemes.com/document/removing-product-product-category-or-shop-from-the-urls/

If you want to keep doing this, add https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/ or modify the .htaccess file to stop redirecting.